# C# add or subtract exact number of days

Tags: c#, oop, datetime, c#-4.0

There will be 2 buttons of toggle.One will be up and other will be down
Query is if current month is of 30 days then it should display 01 Aug 2017 to 16th Aug 2017 when i toggle up it should show 16th Aug to 30th Aug and similar should work for toggle down.
But if current month is of 31 days then it should display 01 Aug 2017 to 16th Aug 2017 and 16th Aug to 31st Aug and similar should work for toggle down.This should work continous if am trying to toggle up it should display like below
1st Jan to 15th jan then 16th to 30th Jan then 1st Feb to 16th Feb like wise it should go on for toggle up and down.
Code which i tried is below :

```
public static DateTime GetEndDate(int year, int month)
{
    decimal currentmonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    decimal value = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(currentmonth / 2));
    // DateTime updatedfinaldatevaluestart = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    DateTime updatedfinaldatevalueend = new DateTime(year, month, Convert.ToInt32(value));
    return updatedfinaldatevalueend;
}

public static DateTime GetStartDate(int year, int month)
{
    decimal currentmonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    decimal value = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(currentmonth / 2));
    // DateTime updatedfinaldatevaluestart = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    DateTime updatedfinaldatevalueend = new DateTime(year, month, 01);
    return updatedfinaldatevalueend;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have encountered? What is your question?

Comment: Problem is i want to display continous weeks like 1st to 15th and then 16 to 30 like so on..But if month is of 31 days then it should show 1st to 15th and 16th to 31st like so on...

Comment: I still can't understand .. looking into your code always 31 days month you will get 16 days.. what you can do is create a condition when the months are January, March, May, July, August, October and December... then you can correct your calc...

Comment: I assume there is more to this problem? Where are the year and month being passed from? Where is the date range EG 16th Aug - 31st Aug, displaying?

Comment: In addition to the 2 x parameters year and month, you will also need to pass a parameter representing the half of the month you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do all these calculations. The first half for all months will always be between the 1st and the 15th (you don't have to calculate 15th. There's no month that has like 45 days). And, the second half will always start from the 16th, and you can get the end date of the month by doing this (`startDate` is the first day of the month):

```
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a better way of doing what you're trying to achieve but there isn't enough information in the question to determine what that is (what is calling these methods, what is happening to the output etc) However, using the method you have posted, this (untested) code may do what you require

The bool parameter should be true when the down button is clicked and false when the up button is clicked

```
    public static DateTime GetEndDate(int year, int month, bool firstHalfOfMonth)
    {
        if (firstHalfOfMonth == false)
        {
            return GetStartDate(year, month, false);
        }
        else
        {
            return new DateTime(year, month, System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));
        }
    }

    public static DateTime GetStartDate(int year, int month, bool firstHalfOfMonth)
    {
        if (firstHalfOfMonth == false)
        {
            int daysInCurrentMonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
            int midMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)daysInCurrentMonth / 2));
            return new DateTime(year, month, midMonth);
        }
        else
        {
            return new DateTime(year, month, 1);
        }
    }
```